# Can I create insert HTML and CSS into a HTML page purely using javascript?

Tags: javascript, fonts

I am currently using a marketplace solution called Arcadier (Arcadier.com) that lets me customize my marketplace only via javascript edits.

Thus I was wondering if I could add a new section with words onto the homepage of the site just by adding a javascript

I’ve made the section purely in HTML (using in-line CSS) here:

```
 <div style="height:400px; width:100%">

    <h1>About Us</h1>

    <div style="max-width:120px;"><img></div>` <p> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,.</p>

    <a href="#">Click here</a>

</div>
```

Is it possible in javascript to render this html into the index.html page?
Currently using dummy text info to see if this solution is viable.

Comment: Certainly JS can add HTML elements to a page, but how does that relate to the "font changer"? Are you saying that you wouldn't add HTML like you've shown, but actually you'd add some HTML controls that allow selection of fonts?

Comment: Apologies, what i really wanted to ask was how to add a new section into the website using purely javascript. How Arcadier works is that it allows customization of HTML and CSS but only with a javascript inserter box.

Comment: @chinny oh, you said you wanted to insert fonts using JavaScript! What the heck is a JavaScript inserter box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to run this code in Javascript. It may help your problem.

```
// Create a div element
var newDiv= document.createElement('div');

// Assign id, it help you to set the style 
newDiv.id = 'NewDiv';


// Dont forget to inspect the html page and get the body class and the class you want to append the new container
$('.page-home .main').append(newDiv);


//Create H2 element
var newH2= document.createElement('h2');


//add the text using innerHTML inside H2 elements
newH2.innerHTML = "I'm the new div";


//then append the H2 element into the div you created
$('#NewDiv').append(newH2);


//for style, use the ID you declare to the element
$('#NewDiv').css({'height':'100px', 'margin-top':'20px', 'text-align':'center'});


//if you want to add some images, you can add only those image from web

var newImg = document.createElement("img");
newImg .id = 'NewImg';
newImg.src = "https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M6507d99cb13e01bdf824b2bd0277cf03H0&pid=15.1&P=0&w=300&h=300";

$('#NewDiv').append(newImg);
$('#NewImg').css({'width':'55px'});
```

HOPE IT WILL HELP YOU :)

Answer (score 0):

I found several examples of creating an element as well as an example of setting the style attribute when I ran a google search.  I used the results to create the below example

```
// Create a div element
var elem = document.createElement("div"); 

//Set elements innerHTML
elem.innerHTML="hey";  


//Add the element to body
document.body.appendChild(elem);

//add style attribute to element
elem.setAttribute('style','color:red');
```